# Diagnostic policy service is not running on windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi, service

I have rebuilt my machine 3 times (Windows 7) and upon next boot the network will not connect. (Wirelessly or Wired)

If I right click to troubleshoot, I receive the error Diagnostic policy service is not running. When I try to start it, I receive "Access Denied : Error 5".

Thus, I have to do a System Restore to get it to work again. However, this is my work laptop. I do not have time to do a system restore and install software every morning for 30min-1hour.

Anyone else have this issue? All I can find it people saying to do a system restore. However, that ONLY works for me until the next time I shut down. Once I boot up - it's broken again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with McAfee Antivirus. Tweaked some security settings and now it works.